# Убрать несколько строк из двумерного массива, содержащего строки

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251>nul");

    //сам текст
    //char txt[] = "I can never be satisfied with anyone who would be blockhead enough to have me.";
    int size = 80;
    char* txt = new char[size];
    cout << "Введите текст:\n"  ;
    cin.get(txt, 80);

    //количество символов
    int s = strlen(txt);
    cout << "Количество символов в тексте: " << s << endl;

    //счетчик слов
    int count=0;
    int slov = 0, i = 0, k = 0, j = 0;

    while (txt[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (txt[i] != ' ' && slov == 0)
        {
            slov = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if (txt[i] == ' ')
        {
            slov = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    slov = count;
    cout << "Количество слов в строке: " << count << endl;

    //создаем двумерный динамический массив
    //строки количество слов
    //столбцы - количество символов в слове
    int** A = new int*[count];
    for (i = 0; i < count ; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new int[s];
        for (j = 0; j < s; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = txt[k];
            k++;
            //если значение отрицательное,то уменьшаем количество строк
            //чтобы ничего лишнего не выводилось на экран
            if (A[i][j] < 0)
            {
                count--;
                break;
            }
            //если в тесте пробел или точка или строка закончилась,то заканчиваем заполнять строку
            // и увеличиваем количество строк
            if (A[i][j] == ' ' || A[i][j] == '\0' || A[i][j] == 46)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }

            cout << char(A[i][j]);  
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Как убрать пустые строки? К примеру, я ввожу:

```
  i    love    you.
```

и должно быть на выводе:

```
i
love
you
```

А у меня выводит:

```
i



love



you
```

Помогите плиз(если несложно,то с примером)!

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вы хотите поправить именно ваш вариант, то можно сделать с помощью булевой переменной, например так:

```
bool isEnded = false;
int** A = new int*[count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    A[i] = new int[s];
    for (j = 0; j < s; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = txt[k];
        k++;
        //если значение отрицательное,то уменьшаем количество строк
        //чтобы ничего лишнего не выводилось на экран
        if (A[i][j] < 0)
        {
            count--;
            break;
        }
        //если в тесте пробел или точка или строка закончилась,то заканчиваем заполнять строку
        // и увеличиваем количество строк
        if (A[i][j] == ' ' || A[i][j] == '\0' || A[i][j] == 46)
        {
            count++;
            if (!isEnded) 
            {
                 cout << endl;
                 isEnded = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        else isEnded = false;
        cout << char(A[i][j]);
    }

}
```